# Onclick function execute on second

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, setinterval

I have 3 functions which increase certain values each second.

So for example

```
var timberinterval = setInterval(function() {
        timber = timber + timbermodifier;           
        document.getElementById('timber').innerText = Math.floor(timber);                   
 }, 1000);
var sulphurinterval = setInterval(function() {
        sulphur = sulphur + sulphurmodifier;           
        document.getElementById('sulphur').innerText = Math.floor(sulphur);                     
 }, 1000);
var goldinterval = setInterval(function() {
        gold = gold + goldmodifier;           
        document.getElementById('gold').innerText = Math.floor(gold);                   
 }, 1000);
```

These functions are controlled by 3 separate buttons. As you can see, each second the functions increase by the modifier.

The user isnt always clicking on the exact second, they may be clicking at 0.5 seconds, or at 0.8 seconds and then my functions start to run out of sync.

How do I delay the functions execution so that it is in sync with the other functions?

Comment: There is no easy way to sync the functions so simply use only one interval-function where all elements are updated - and let the buttons control the "(timber|sulphur|gold)modifier"

Comment: That still would break the synchronization, its just it would break it for all 3, not just 1, as I do need it to be run every second (real time). Is there a way to get functions to be based on the global clock?

Comment: Add your full code so we could help...

Comment: Ah you want to sync to the system clock's seconds? You will have to examine the time then within your function, there is no native way of doing this. 
The interval does even not guarantee it is called exactly every 1000ms, to get an accurate measurement you should use setTimeout(), calculate time elapsed, update your (timber|sulphur|gold) according to the elapsed time  and setTimeout again.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki http://eg-graphics.com/PirateCove/PirateCove.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the current milliseconds:

```
var d = new Date();
var milli = d.getMilliseconds();
```

You could then call the setInterval function inside a setTimeout function:

```
setTimeout(function() { setInterval(function() { ... }, 1000); }, 1000-milli)
```

However, if you need to have the return value for setInterval (for example to clear the interval), I believe you will have to work with promises.

Comment: That kinda works, but I get a few issues. On my initial setup i get the following code to run, but the functions run 1 second apart, how to fix? `setTimeout(function() {
  timberupdates(timber, timbermodifier); 
  sulphurupdates(sulphur, sulphurmodifier);
  goldupdates(gold, goldmodifier);
 }, 1000-milli); `

Comment: _the functions run 1 second apart_ - I don't understand what you mean there

Comment: http://eg-graphics.com/PirateCove/PirateCove.html as you open the page, on load, you will see the numbers 50, 51, 52 appear. They should appear all at one time, instead they appear one by one.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you added the setTimeout to both the very first call and the timberupdates() function. Try removing it from the timberupdates() function.

Comment: If I do that, then the functions fall out of sync

Comment: Oh, I just saw that you're also calling timberupdates on button click. Get rid of setTimeout in timberupdates and make timbermodifier (& sulphur/goldmodifier) global variables. Then, when the button 'timberupdate' is clicked, just increment the timbermodifier variable, don't call timberupdates() again. That way the interval is constantly running, always incrementing by the current value of timbermodifier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158690/discussion-between-e-villiger-and-egxo).

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/419/)**.

I suggest the use of global variables inside the same `setInterval` to ensure the synchronisation like the snippet below shows.

Hope this helps.

**Start on click example :**

```js
var timbermodifier,sulphurmodifier,goldmodifier,timber,sulphur,gold;
timbermodifier = sulphurmodifier = goldmodifier = 1;
timber = sulphur = gold = 0;
timber_flag = sulphur_flag = gold_flag = false;

document.getElementById("timber-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  timber_flag = true;
});
document.getElementById("sulphur-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  sulphur_flag = true;
});
document.getElementById("gold-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  gold_flag = true;
});

var global_interval = setInterval(function() {
  if ( timber_flag ) {
    timber = timber + timbermodifier;
    document.getElementById('timber').innerText = Math.floor(timber);
  }

  if ( sulphur_flag ) {
    sulphur = sulphur + sulphurmodifier;
    document.getElementById('sulphur').innerText = Math.floor(sulphur);
  }

  if ( gold_flag ) {
    gold = gold + goldmodifier;
    document.getElementById('gold').innerText = Math.floor(gold);
  }
}, 1000);

//clearInterval(global_interval);
```

```html
<button id="timber-btn">Timber</button> <span id="timber"></span><br>
<button id="sulphur-btn">Sulphur</button> <span id="sulphur"></span><br>
<button id="gold-btn">Gold</button> <span id="gold"></span>
```

**Toggle '`stop/start`' on click example :**

```js
var timbermodifier,sulphurmodifier,goldmodifier;
var timber,sulphur,gold;
timbermodifier = sulphurmodifier = goldmodifier = 1;
timber = sulphur = gold = 0;
timber_flag = sulphur_flag = gold_flag = true;

document.getElementById("timber-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  timber_flag = timber_flag ? false : true;
});
document.getElementById("sulphur-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  sulphur_flag = sulphur_flag ? false : true;
});
document.getElementById("gold-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  gold_flag = gold_flag ? false : true;
});

var global_interval = setInterval(function() {
  if ( timber_flag ) {
    timber = timber + timbermodifier;
    document.getElementById('timber').innerText = Math.floor(timber);
  }

  if ( sulphur_flag ) {
    sulphur = sulphur + sulphurmodifier;
    document.getElementById('sulphur').innerText = Math.floor(sulphur);
  }

  if ( gold_flag ) {
    gold = gold + goldmodifier;
    document.getElementById('gold').innerText = Math.floor(gold);
  }
}, 1000);

//clearInterval(global_interval);
```

```html
<button id="timber-btn">Timber</button> <span id="timber"></span><br>
<button id="sulphur-btn">Sulphur</button> <span id="sulphur"></span><br>
<button id="gold-btn">Gold</button> <span id="gold"></span>
```